# Jquery: if and else

Tags: jquery, css, if-statement

```
$("#bottomWatch").click(function(){
                var doops = $(".videoMove").display;

                if (doops == "none") {  
                $("#video").css("left","15%", "display: block");
                 } else {
                $(".videoMove").css("left","200%", "display: none");
                });
```

Do I have the right idea here? How would I do this? I want to click the button and if the id is hidden than it gets displayed as block and pulled in and if it is not than it travels back 200% and hides itself.

Toggle will not work with what I am doing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use the [`is`](http://api.jquery.com/is) method:

```
if ($('.videoMove').is(':hidden')) {
    ...
} else {
    ...
}
```

Comment: So how should my code look? I understand that is is key, but I failed to make it work

Comment: @GARR, honestly, if you can't tell how to add an `if` statement in your jQuery code, you should stop using jQuery altogether and focus on learning the basics of JavaScript. Something like [codecademy](http://www.codecademy.com/) might be helpful, although I can't vouch for it.

Comment: I know if statements well enough, just not for jquery; this should be working but it is not. I decided to frankenstein code it after attempts, but it has not worked. So I have this http://pastebin.com/67d9wXt8

Comment: Got it to work with this if ($('.videoMove').css('left') === '200%')

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$("#bottomWatch").click(function() {
    if ($(".videoMove").is(":hidden")) {
        console.log("hidden");
        $('.videoMove').show().animate({
            'left': '200px',
        }, "slow", function() {
           //callback
        });
    } else {
        $('.videoMove').animate({
            'left': '280px'
        }, "slow", function() {
            //done
            $(this).hide();
        });
    }
});​
```

Working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4y6LA/1/)

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($(".videoMove").is(":hidden")) {
   ///...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

.display is not a jQuery Property ...

Replace

```
var doops = $(".videoMove").display;
```

with

```
var doops = $(".videoMove").css('display');   // jQuery Object
```

OR

```
 var doops = $(".videoMove").get().style.display;  // DOM Object
```